# mysql get minutes between a datetime and NOW()

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to calculate how many minutes have elapsed between a saved DateTime and NOW(), how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_col)) / 60)
```

Comment: That is returning the seconds between both time stamps. You still need to divide it by 60 and round the result appropriately.

Answer (score 25):

Use the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) built-in function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, my_datatime_col, now())
```

You may have to swap the datetime values to get the right sign (positive/negative) on the result if the column is before/after "now".

Answer (score 2):

Just search for `TIMEDIFF` function in MySQL docs.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using the UNIX epoch (as per rkosegi and Holger Just)

```
SELECT ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datefield))/60);
```